# Cauchy-Riemann equation problem.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = 2x + ixy^2$

I tried to use C-R equation to solve for this and got

$$
  \frac{du}{dx} = 2
  \quad\quad\quad
  \frac{du}{dy} = 0
  \quad\quad\quad
  \frac{dv}{dx} = y^2
  \quad\quad\quad
  \frac{dv}{dy} = 2xy
$$

What should I do next to proof that C-R equation still hold or not ?

Comment: Is $2 = 2xy$?  Is $0 = -y^2$?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably supposed to argue for which $x,y$ the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold true and moreover if the function is analytic (or holomorphic if that's the term you're using) based on the domain on which the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold true. Setting up the Cauchy-Riemann equations, we have

$$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{dv}{dy} \Longrightarrow 2 = 2xy$$

and

$$\frac{du}{dy} = -\frac{dv}{dx} \Longrightarrow 0 = -y^2.$$

From the second equation, we see that $y$ must be $0$. Can the first equation be solved then? What can you conclude about $f$?